# Using GitHub with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

This is probably a stupid question but I have downloaded EGit, created in GitHub, and I am able to commit/push using the command line. However, I couldn't figure out how to commit/push files to a specific repo in GitHub. I can do Team->share->create git repo etc. but can't seem to push anything. How am I supposed to link a java project with a repo on GitHub(or generally any Git repo)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first create the repo on Github, then [clone](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Cloning_remote_Repositories) it with EGit and then push to it like to any other repository. Of course you first need to setup the encryption keys correctly.